# Is the off-topic answer to off-topic question "not an answer"?

Tags: discussion, flags, answers, scope

I've flagged [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25667157/531954) answer as 'not an answer'.

The reason is, the answer is not about programming. It's the answer to the question that is clearly off-topic (about interviewing process, not about programming issues). My flag was refused.

Well, technically it **is** an answer, only not an answer that should be posted on Stack Overflow. It belongs to the Workplace, maybe to the Programmers, but not to SO.

Is it correct to flag such answers as "not an answer" or "very low quality"?

**pros:**

- answering off-topic questions should be discouraged
- active off-topic topics encourage others to post similar questions on SO, to increase the chances of getting answer

**contras:**

- handling such flags consumes precious moderators' time

Comment: Thanks for linking the question. I learned something from it, even if it is awfully formulated. It might even be a hidden, hidden pearl.

Comment: `Well, technically it is an answer...`, there you have it, it is an answer.  So you don't think the user should have answered the question, then downvote it, but a bad answer or an answer to a bad/off-topic question is still an answer and there is no flag for "bad answer".

Comment: @psubsee2003 what about "very low quality"?

Comment: @JanDvorak I think that depends on just how bad the answer is.  (and in this case, VLQ wouldn't be in play since the answer is positively scored).

Comment: It's gone now..

Comment: Well, what if the question is migrated to the appropriate website? Your "not an answer" becomes an answer.

Comment: What @SalmanA said. If a question is OT on SO but on-topic for another SE site, I think it's reasonable to answer it in the assumption that it will be moved to the appropriate site. In that sense, flagging, trying to delete, or downvoting the answer seems counter-productive and harmful to the quality of the eventual results (question with good answer on another SE site).

Comment: Don't penalise the answer, for the sins of the question.

Answer (score 49):

"Not an Answer" flags are for posts that aren't an answer to *any* question.

- I'm having the same problem. Any solution?
- This didn't fix it.
- I'm having a related issue, which I will now describe in detail...
- Hey, aren't you that guy from that place?
- That worked for me!
- asdfghjkl;

Otherwise, if it is an answer—even if it's a poor, misguided, possibly dangerous, answer—you should downvote, comment, edit, and (if you have the appropriate amount of reputation points) vote to delete as appropriate.

Since it seems the *question* is the real problem, downvote, comment, and/or vote/flag to close as appropriate.

Comment: I happened on one of these just a few hours ago, and I did exactly that. I flagged the question and left the answer as Looks ok.

Comment: "If it's an answer, even if it's a poor, misguided, possibly dangerous,.." I think you meant to say, "If it's a poor, misguided, possibly dangerous,...".. Unless, perhaps, you suggest people should downvote answers?