# Why was my "not an answer" flag declined as having no evidence?

Tags: discussion

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28491594/242520) to [What is the purpose of message queues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28491386/what-is-the-purpose-of-message-queues) as "not an answer". When I went to flag another answer I was told my last flag was declined and I should review it.

The result of the flag is as follows:

[image]

The answer I flagged is as follows:

[image]

<sub>I've edited the answering user's information out.</sub>

The answer begins straight away with a question, which should already set off anyone's *not an answer* spidey-sense. Then it goes on to talk about MSMQ which does nothing to answer the question of what purpose message queues serve.

To me it's not even a matter of opinion, it's clearly not an answer to the question. It's self-evident. And at least one other person agrees with me.

Comment: _"The answer begins straight away with a question, which should already set off anyone's not an answer spidey-sense."_ You should avoid knee-jerk reactions; that question is rhetorical and is not the meat of the post. Your flag was invalid.

Comment: This is an answer.  Read the second paragraph as well as the first.  "Not an answer" means that something is not an answer at all, not that it's not an answer to the question asked and not that it contains a question mark.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit *that question is rhetorical* It isn't rhetorical. If the OP came back and said "I'm on Linux" it would change the given "answer". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_question *A rhetorical question is a figure of speech in the form of a question that is asked in order to make a point, rather than to elicit an answer*

Comment: @ta.speot.is: Exactly. It's rhetorical. It introduces an assumption.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I cannot fathom what meaningful assumption *What is the operating system that your applications are running on?* introduces, aside from that we are assuming OP has an application and an operating system. The question is not rhetorical.

Comment: @ta.speot.is: I don't know how to explain it to you then. It is very clear and unambiguous to me. It's _clearly_ an answer, and one that introduces the notion that the answer's validity will depend on the answer to the question "what OS are you running?" when it goes on to provide suggestions for when the answer is "Windows". It's not difficult to parse.

Comment: It's an answer. "On windows servers you can use MSMQ and it comes with the OS". It might - or might not - be a _good_ answer, but flagging is for 'delete this because it is junk'. Not 'it's not a very good answer' which is what downvotes are for.

Comment: @ta.speot.is All answers make assumptions to some degree - the first sentence is simply a qualification of the assumptions being made in the answer. Whether or not the magnitude of the assumption is appropriate is a matter of opinion but either way your flag is still invalid because it is still an answer, even if it is (debatably) a grossly presumptuous one.

Comment: Any chance that flag was declined with "random" reason since question was already removed?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's a terrible answer, because it in no way provides the information the question asked for, but it is still in the form of an answer.  Downvoting is the correct action, not flagging.

> The answer begins straight away with a question, which should already set off anyone's not an answer spidey-sense.

Well, it shouldn't.  Instead of worrying about whether there's a question mark in the answer, worry about whether it is informative, asking for clarification, asking what ought to be a new question, or bandwagon jumping.

In this example, the first line appears to ask for clarification, but its actual function is to warn readers about the assumptions made in this answer.  There is nothing at all wrong with that.

Comment: The criteria for "not an answer" is *This was posted as an answer, but it **does not attempt to answer the question**. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.* It's not answering the question at all. It's answering *a* question. I've had plenty of flags accepted for "answers" in answer format that miss the point of the question entirely. And as for the question in the answer, yes it should set off your spidey-sense. It's not rhetorical and serves no expository purpose.

Comment: @ta.speot.is: This has been explained to death on Meta.  The actual criteria is "it does not attempt to answer **any** question"/is not informative.  Being wrong or missing the point are judgements requiring expertise.  Voting works on expertise.  Flagging does not.  A good flag does not require the moderator to know anything at all about the technology involved.

Comment: @ta.speot.is: Ahh, so you agree that starting with a question isn't a problem, your beef is when the question doesn't serve an expository purpose.  Well, in my estimation, it does, as I explained.

Comment: @ta.speot.is: See here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270733/103167

Comment: *This has been explained to death on Meta* I searched a bit harder ([this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22not%20an%20answer%22) instead of [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=not%20an%20answer)) and found [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/242520) which I will accept as the community's standard of what "not an answer" flags should be. Thanks.

Comment: Where did the word "any" come from? That's not what the reason says in the flag dialog. And it really doesn't take any expertise at all to determine that "This comes with the OS and needs to be enabled" does not even remotely address the question "What is the purpose of this?" Are we advocating that, just because they attempted to answer *something* tangentially related to the question, users should only downvote and not try to get blatantly crap content off the site? As an aside, though, all of this user's answers followed this same pattern, and they've all been deleted now.

Comment: @animuson See Ben's comments, it seems that's what the community wants.

Comment: @animuson: That's what's been explained time and again.  Here's another: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/103167  Why do you equate "don't flag" with "not try to get blatantly crap content off the site"?  Downvotes do get crap off the site (negatively scored answers can be deleted by high rep users), but the decision is made by experts, not moderators.

Comment: Just because one user incorrectly used the word "any" does not mean it's policy. I refer to [Shog's informative post on the subject](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer), particularly to the apples. This user clearly gave us a banana and not an apple.

Comment: But I suppose in this particular case we also have to consider whether this was an honest attempt at answering the question, which I don't believe it was based on the user's other answers on other questions. They appear to just be hitting random questions and posting things based on keywords to see if anything sticks.

Comment: @animuson: Well, that would call for a custom flag, not a NAA.  Also, I've seen an answer by Shog with pretty much exactly the same list as Fish Below The Ice provided -- NAA fall into certain categories, and anything outside those is an attempt to answer (although it may be a miserable failure).

Comment: @animuson: Here, exactly the same guidelines from a diamond mod: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268438/103167  Especially consider the "If your flag requires a mod to evaluate an answer from the question's perspective, do not use a "Not an Answer" flag on it."

Comment: I guess I put more effort into NAA flags than some others do, because I do usually look at the question when I'm not completely sure why it was flagged, and have been spending more time in the Low Quality Posts queue where the question is displayed. I definitely would have flat-out deleted this if it was presented to me.

Comment: @animuson: Good of you. Though as long as there is no consensus, at least as far as moderators are concerned, which should also be reflected in the flag-text, it will still be extremely arbitrary and irritating.

Comment: And this is why the safest option is to use NAA for extremely egregious cases only, although it's beginning to look like we can't even agree on what constitutes "extremely egregious" either. (This I wouldn't consider an example of egregiousness.)

Comment: @animuson: I think you're somewhat alone among moderators with your approach. Not saying that it's bad at all, just that it's different from guidelines we got from other moderators. Here's a quote from Brad (with emphasis added by me) about another declined NAA flag: "That class of flag is only used for things that you can tell are gibberish, "me too" replies, or follow-on questions **without reading anything else**."

Comment: Robert, George, (I believe) Brad, and even [Will](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268409/) have repeatedly expressed the idea that you diamond holders will not and should not have to look at the questions when handling NAA flags, @animuson. [MichaelT's "What constitutes an answer?"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277048) is a good summation, and links to [Why was this "not an answer" flag declined?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268369) which probably has the most firmly stated take of the prevailing mod view. You seem to be unique in this regard, and it's nice to hear that you do that.

Comment: @animuson well, [check this out](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276197/792066). Apparently, mods doesn't have to read the question to deal with NAA's (through reviewers do).

Answer (score 12):

"Not an answer" doesn't mean "not *the* answer", which would require expertise and value judgements to determine. We have upvotes and downvotes to express our agreement with the value of an answer as it pertains to the question.

"Not an answer" is for something that cannot remotely have been considered *by the author* to be any sort of attempt at answering. That means, outright new questions, "me too" remarks, expressions of gratitude, commentary, and so forth.

This answer fits in the latter category as the answer was *clearly* misplaced and, as such, your flag was valid to my mind.

As an aside, I also wish to reiterate that I'm getting sick to death of seeing that canned comment text everywhere. The post was obviously not a "critique" or a "request for clarification", yet the reviewer has opted to dump that comment underneath it anyway instead of taking a moment to write something that actually fits. It makes me concerned for the amount of care and attention that reviewers actually spend on reviewing.

Comment: *which would require expertise and value judgements to determine* My issue is not whether moderates should judge the answer on correctness. It's not reasonable to require moderators to make this assessment because it requires domain knowledge and Stack Overflow is very broad and no one moderate could understand every topic discussed. I flagged the "answer" as "not an answer" because the question is "What is the purpose of X" and the "answer" is "Y is an X". It requires only elementary critical thinking to see that it's not an answer; there's no "right" or "wrong" assessment to be made.

Comment: At any rate, I accepted Ben's answer because it seems the community has an opinion on what "not an answer" is. I just find that opinion very unsatisfactory for the reasons I've given above.

Comment: @ta.speot.is I tried to avoid insulting you, but if you're going down these lines.... _"It requires only elementary critical thinking"_ No, it requires only elementary critical thinking and English language comprehension to see that 'not an answer' is an invalid flag here. You appear to be the only one who doesn't see it, yet you're stubbornly sticking to your "alternative" viewpoint. Which is odd.

Comment: *You appear to be the only one who doesn't see it, yet you're stubbornly sticking to your "alternative" viewpoint.* I understand the community wants anything that's literally not an answer to be considered "not an answer" (which is why *I accepted Ben's answer*) but I think that's an extremely low standard and I find it extremely unsatisfactory. Again, *I accepted Ben's answer* because the community has some consensus about the matter and was quite prepared to leave it that but other people keep posting.

Comment: @ta.speot.is: I appreciate the desire to maintain high standards. Honestly, I do. I support it. But at the same time I'm acutely aware that, when we're talking about _whether an answer is correct_ in its attempt to answer the question, we _must_ yield to peer review and community voting, otherwise it becomes a battle of "he said, she said" and of a select few dictating what is and is not correct in any given domain. That's why we use votes for that, not flagging. Flagging is restricted for posts that clearly aren't even in the running at all! Hopefully that's a bit clearer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Are you saying that if someone had answered "I like turtles. And message queues." it would not be a NAA candidate? The text under the NAA flag option clearly says _"This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether. "_ the "answer" here ___did not___ make any attempt to answer the question, so based on the description in the Flag popup box, it ___is___ a candidate for NAA. If that text is incorrect or incomplete, perhaps it could be improved?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: _You appear to be the only one ..._ - did you see animuson♦'s comments on the other answer? Obviously, even some moderators agree with that viewpoint and it's not at all clear-cut. Also, the flag description text does say "... it does not attempt to answer **the** question." Perhaps the consensus is that the flag should only be used when the post can't answer any question at all, but that's definitely not what the description says, and if so, the description should possibly be updated.

Comment: @AleksiTorhamo: It _is_ what the description says. A failure to answer the question is not the same as not attempting to in the first place! Any system that involves flagging for deletion by a select few on the basis of domain-specific merit judgements is _broken_, so it is self-evident that this is _not_ what the answer-flagging system is for. That's how it's always been since the dawn of SO. If you think the post is a _wrong_ answer, downvote it; if it is an advertisement, or a thank you, or a [non-rhetorical] question, or a new question for a new OP's own benefit, flag it. Simples! :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit As ta.speot.is has already pointed out, domain specific merit judgment is _not_ required in this case. If someone had asked "What is the purpose of forks?" and the answer was "Do you like Swedish products? You can buy forks at Ikea.", you do not have to be a fork expert to see that the answer provided is not an answer to the question.

Comment: @JLRishe: Completely true, and completely irrelevant as that is not an equivalent example!

Comment: Oh, balls, how did I miss this? This entire time I've been connecting this flagged answer with an _entirely_ different question. This answer goes way above the NAA threshold by being nonsensically irrelevant to the question. Yes, I believe that is NAA. Dammit. /cc @ta.speot.is

Comment: Well then, have an upvote! :)

Comment: And one from me.

Comment: @Lightness That long conversation of comments really makes things very confusing since your edit. Kept me on my toes trying to figure out what was going on. Especially after I upvoted you to start off with.